# Servicing Interrupt while it disabled for some period

Tags: microcontroller

Consider there are 4 interrupt I enabled in the microcontroller. As the first interrupt is serviced, I am entering in to protected section(All other interrupt are disabled) for doing important calculation. My question is, While code is in protected section, if other interrupt is supposed to give a interrupt will disabled completely or it will be in hold, so that it will give interrupt after exiting from protected section.

Comment: What microcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

What I would suspect would happen is that when a particular event occurs, the interrupt flag is set. If all interrupts are disabled, then only the flag is set and no jump instruction is issued. When you enable interrupts, if an interrupt flag was set, then the corresponding jump instruction would happen.

But you're best bet is to read the datasheet for the microcontroller because it will tell what would happen.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that disabling interrupts globally for too long can cause issues for other events that use interrupts for processing. For example if you receive a serial data over UART an overrun error can occur if you don't read the data from the buffer (or even a FIFO) fast enough.
 Make sure that you allow less time consuming ISRs to still run while running longer ISRs.

Answer (score 0):

Second or any other interrupt will be serviced (and will stop executing first) only in case if it has a higher priority level, if not it will be waiting (in pending state) on first interrupt to finish and when first interrupt exits from ISR, second interrupt will be serviced.